# How to store python dictionary in to mysql DB through python

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am trying to store the the following dictionary into mysql DB by converting the dictionary into a string and then trying to insert, but I am getting following error. How can this be solved, or is there any other way to store a dictionary into mysql DB?

```
dic = {'office': {'component_office': ['Word2010SP0', 'PowerPoint2010SP0']}}
d = str(dic)

# Sql query
sql = "INSERT INTO ep_soft(ip_address, soft_data) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % ("192.xxx.xx.xx", d )

soft_data is a VARCHAR(500)
```

Error:
    execution exception (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that                               corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'office': {'component_office': ['Word2010SP0', 'PowerPoint2010SP0' at line 1")

Any suggestions or help please?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, don't ever construct raw SQL queries like that. Never ever. This is what parametrized queries are for. You've asking for an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

If you want to store arbitrary data, as for example Python dictionaries, you should serialize that data. [JSON](http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/json.html) would be good choice for the format.

Overall your code should look like this:

```
import MySQLdb
import json

db = MySQLdb.connect(...)    
cursor = db.cursor() 

dic = {'office': {'component_office': ['Word2010SP0', 'PowerPoint2010SP0']}}
sql = "INSERT INTO ep_soft(ip_address, soft_data) VALUES (%s, %s)"

cursor.execute(sql, ("192.xxx.xx.xx", json.dumps(dic)))
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: How to deserialize data at the server other end ?

Comment: @VignanBandi: `dic = json.loads(str_from_db)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below:

```
dic = {'office': {'component_office': ['Word2010SP0', 'PowerPoint2010SP0']}}
d = str(dic)

# Sql query
sql = """INSERT INTO ep_soft(ip_address, soft_data) VALUES (%r, %r)""" % ("192.xxx.xx.xx", d )
```

Comment: It still throwing the same error (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'192.xxx.x.xxx\'\', \'"{\'component_office\': [\'Word2010SP0\']}"\' at line 1')

Comment: OK, change d = str(dict) by d = json.dumps(dic).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs MySQLdb.escape_string() solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dic = { 'office': {'component_office': ['Word2010SP0', 'PowerPoint2010SP0'] } }

"INSERT INTO `db`.`table`(`ip_address`, `soft_data`) VALUES (`{}`, `{}`)".format("192.xxx.xx.xx", str(dic))
```

Change `db` and `table` to the values you need.

Comment: by doing this im getting following exception (1054, "Unknown column '192.xx.xx.xxx' in 'field list'")

Comment: Change `d` in the `INSERT` to `dic`

Comment: I tried the script and it works ok can you print your code and traceback? it's hard to understand where is the error, one more option try only the SQL statement at mysql work-branch.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs MySQLdb.escape_string() solves the problem

Comment: Incase anyone is reading this in not 2013: The error is due to the back ticks around the curly braces. They should be single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to sanitize your inputs, and '.format' is useful when needing to use the same variable multiple times within a query. (Not that you to for this example)

```
dic = {'office': {'component_office': ['Word2010SP0', 'PowerPoint2010SP0']}}
ip = '192.xxx.xx.xx'
with conn.cursor() as cur:
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO `ep_soft`(`ip_address`, `soft_data`) VALUES ({0}, '{1}')".format(cur.escape(ip),json.dumps(event)))
  conn.commit()
```

If you do not use cur.escape(variable), you will need to enclose the placeholder {} in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has some pseudo code regarding the connection object and the flavor of mysql is memsql, but other than that it should be straightforward to follow.

```
import json
#... do something
a_big_dict = getAHugeDict()  #build a huge python dict
conn = getMeAConnection(...)
serialized_dict = json.dumps(a_big_dict) #serialize dict to string
#Something like this to hold the serialization...
qry_create = """
CREATE TABLE TABLE_OF_BIG_DICTS (
ROWID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
SERIALIZED_DICT BLOB NOT NULL,
UPLOAD_DT TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
KEY (`ROWID`) USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
);
"""
conn.execute(qry_create)
#Something like this to hold em'
qry_insert = """
INSERT INTO TABLE_OF_BIG_DICTS (SERIALIZED_DICT)
SELECT '{SERIALIZED_DICT}' as SERIALIZED_DICT;
"""
#Send it to db
conn.execute(qry_insert.format(SERIALIZED_DICT=serialized_dict))
#grab the latest
qry_read = """
SELECT a.SERIALIZED_DICT
from TABLE_OF_BIG_DICTS a
JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(UPLOAD_DT) AS MAX_UPLOAD_DT
    FROM TABLE_OF_BIG_DICTS
)                           b
ON  a.UPLOAD_DT = b.MAX_UPLOAD_DT
LIMIT 1
"""

#something like this to read the latest dict...
df_dict = conn.sql_to_dataframe(qry_read)
dict_str = df_dict.iloc[df_dict.index.min()][0]

#dicts never die they just get rebuilt
dict_better = json.loads(dict_str)
```